# Create custom session variables in opencart 2.x

Tags: php, session, opencart2.x

I would like to create some custom session variables in **OpenCart 2.3.x.** 
Specifically, when user creates a new product I would like to create one session variable. So far in order to do this, I have create inside `session.php` file (`system/library/session.php`) a public function and inside I have this:

```
public function 
sessionCustomNames($session_custom_name, $value) {
   $this->session_id->$session_custom_name = $value;
$this->data = $this->session_id->$session_custom_name;

return $this->data;
}
```

Now, inside any controller file, I would like to call this function and set a key-value pair.
for example:

```
 sessionCustomNames('prosuct_id', 30)
```

Obviously, I did something wrong and the above does not work. but the logic is this I have described. could you tell me what could I do in order to accomplished that?